# How do you insert javascript code into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have learned to build a fun piece of javascript on codeacademy and wanted to add it on a html document. How would I go about doing this or is it even possible?

Here is the site. I tried to use script tags but they do not work. Not sure if I am putting them in the right place.

http://www.codecademy.com/courses/animate-your-name/0/2

Comment: Actually it's alright. Could you post your entire code, or the code that you wanted to add to your document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Codeacademy link, it seems as if there are some dependancies. You need to make sure to include those. Your HTML file should look like this. Note: You should probably combine all of your JS into an external file and link it with `<script src="main.js"></script>` tags. Also, make sure that your script tags come at the end of the page (but before the `</body>`), it will make your page faster as your JS won't block the DOM construction.

**Update**

If you included all of the known dependancies and it still doesn't seem to work, Codecademy probably buried some important code somewhere. The easiest way to get around this would be to just download the web page itself as an HTML file (option click on the link on mac) and either use that or poke around to make sure you have everything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script>
var myName = "Codecademy";

var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

drawName(myName, letterColors);

if(10 < 3)
{
    bubbleShape = 'square';
}
else
{
    bubbleShape = 'circle';
}

bounceBubbles();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry new to javascript or coding in general.<script src="YOUR_CUSTOM_JS.js"></script> I changed it to my .js but when i open html page nothing happens

Comment: Ok so I instead of just linking the file, you can just include it inline. Just copy and paste the code into your text editor, save and open in your browser.

Comment: So i copied and pasted code and still nothing happens. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Ok, I'm looking back at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add inline JavaScript by using the `<script>` tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

### EDIT

Sorry I didn't notice that you've already tried the script tags.  Can you post your HTML with the script tags?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Result</title>
   <script>
 var myName = "Codecademy";
 var red = [0, 100, 63];
 var orange = [40, 100, 60];
 var green = [75, 100, 40];
 var blue = [196, 77, 55];
 var purple = [280, 50, 60];
 var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

drawName(myName, letterColors);

if(10 < 3)
{
    bubbleShape = 'square';
}
else
{
    bubbleShape = 'circle';
}

bounceBubbles();
</script>
 </head>
 <body><h1>YEAH SANDWICHES</h1>
 <img src="http://bit.ly/RhrMEn" />
  <p>I like eggs.</p>
  <p>And ham!</p>
  <p>But mostly sandwiches.</p>

 </body>
</html>

Comment: how do I turn it into readable html in stackoverflow so it doesnt look like the mess above?

Comment: @user3802773 Try to avoid putting a bunch of code in your comments.  Edit your question above instead.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the `<script>` tags:

```
<script src="helloWorld.js"></script>
```

OR:

```
<script>
//Your Js Goes Here
</script>
```

Hope this is what you needed!